How can I make table in postgres have ownership from Role than user?
I have integrated vault with postgres and my application, so when a migration job is running it connects with vault creates credentials in postgres. All works well until I found when a new table is created by migration job it assign the temporary role ownership to that table. later when the job runs again it fails to access that table that have ownership of previously created user.
I tried to do SET ROLE but i realized that it wont work via vault as it works only on active session.
I am not sure how can i do this, if anyone have this experience of handling the dynamic credentials
I am expecting
I would rather try make a migration role, and grant that role to the user and make sure that the role is owner of the table
vault write database/roles/user-db-migration \
    db_name="postgresql-user-database" \
    default_ttl="5h" \
    max_ttl="12h" \
    creation_statements="
        CREATE ROLE \"{{name}}\" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; \
    SET ROLE admin_user; \
        ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO \"{{name}}\"; \
        GRANT admin_user TO \"{{name}}\";" \
    revocation_statements="
        ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM \"{{name}}\"; \
        REVOKE admin_user FROM \"{{name}}\"; \
        DROP ROLE \"{{name}}\";"

